# Moving nav-bar to another div in lg breakpoint

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I used Bootstrap 5.3 to create offcanvas nav-bar with hamburger icon in smaller versions that returns to normal menu after certain breakpoint. But can anyone help me with moving the hamburger icon to another div after certain breakpoint?

I tried to create something like below, where the logo (defined the target div with id="logo") is the target where the icon should move after lg-breakpoint (when screen is getting smaller):

Can anyone help me with this? Any ideas? :)

Added nav-bar code (the basic Bootstrap code):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler border-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#navbarOffcanvasLg" aria-controls="navbarOffcanvasLg">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="navbarOffcanvasLg"
              aria-labelledby="navbarOffcanvasLgLabel">
<div class="offcanvas-header"><h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Men&uuml;&uuml;</h5>
<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button></div><div class="offcanvas-body">...
```

The div where I try to move it after lg breakpoint:

```
<div class="col-6 g-0" id="logo">...</div>
```

Comment: Most certainly the wrong approach. Please include a [repro] and images about what you want to move where.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: CSS can not "move" elements to a different position in the DOM.